# Unable to start GCM intent service

Tags: android, push-notification, android-service, google-cloud-messaging

Hi everyone I am experiencing with google GCM but for some reason my GCM intenet service refuses to wake on registration event  - I know I am doing something wrong I just cant figure out what...

Here is my manifest file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dmx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.dmx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.dmx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <activity android:name="com.dmx.ui.ActivitySplashScreen" >

        </activity>

        <!-- ActivitySplashScreen Screen -->
        <activity android:name="com.dmx.ui.ActivityLoginRegister" >
        </activity>

        <!-- Login Screen -->
        <activity android:name="com.dmx.ui.ActivityLogin" >
        </activity>


        <!-- Broadcasr Reciever Declaration For Incoming Messages -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.dmx" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- GCM Service Declaration -->
        <service android:name="com.dmx.logic.services.GCMIntentService" ></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the logcat output -

```
04-18 06:53:39.561: D/PowerManagerService(2959): [api] handleWakeLockDeath : release WakeLock : PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK              'GCM_LIB' (uid=10218, pid=31431, ws=null) (elapsedTime=110364)
04-18 06:53:42.316: W/ActivityManager(2959): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.tmc.logic.services.GCMIntentService } U=0: not found
04-18 06:53:43.821: I/PCWCLIENTTRACE_PushUtil(28180): getPushTypeList : [SPP, GCM]
04-18 06:53:44.826: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(31887): GCM IntentService class: com.tmc.GCMIntentService
04-18 06:53:44.831: W/ActivityManager(2959): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION flg=0x10 pkg=com.tmc cmp=com.tmc/.GCMIntentService (has extras) } U=0: not found
```

I already double checked the service is nested inside the application and also tried to start it via intent...its just dont work....any help???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver` broadcast receiver. That class expects the intent service class to be in the main package of your app - `com.dmx` in your case. But since you put your intent service in `com.dmx.logic.services`, it's not found.

You can see in the logcat that it expects `GCMIntentService` to be in `com.tmc` :

> 04-18 06:53:44.826: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(31887): GCM IntentService
>   class: com.tmc.GCMIntentService 04-18 06:53:44.831:
>   W/ActivityManager(2959): Unable to start service Intent {
>   act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION flg=0x10 pkg=com.tmc
>   cmp=com.tmc/.GCMIntentService (has extras) } U=0: not found

You should either move your intent service class to the main package, or change the broadcast receiver to look for it in its current location.